# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined at Object.toggleCompleted

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my 'toggleCompleted' method. The error states:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined
at Object.toggleCompleted (script.js:23)
```

```
var todoList = { 
  todos: [],
  displayTodos: function () {
    console.log('My Todos:', this.todos);
  },
  addTodo: function(todoText) {
    this.todos.push({ 
      todoText: todoText,
      completed: false
    });
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  changeTodo: function(position, todoText) {
    this.todos[position].todoText = todoText;
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  deleteTodo: function(position) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleCompleted: function(position) {
  var todo = this.todos[position]; // This is the line that is giving me issues
  todo.completed = !todo.completed; 
  this.displayTodos();
  }
};
```

I expect the object to display two things: that the function `todoList.toggleCompleted` allows me to insert any string I want, and when I enter the string the completed property displays true.

I would like to know how to fix the problem. I am calling the method this way: todoList.toggleCompleted('hello there');

Comment: Please show us how you are calling the method.

Comment: `this.todos` is an array, yet with how you are calling `toggleCompleted`, you are trying to access `this.todos["hello there"]`, which isn't going to exist. Arrays (usually) have numbers as their only indices.

Comment: I apologize, I just included how I am calling method in my post, but I am calling it this way:

todoList.toggleCompleted('hello there');

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to: `var todos = []; console.log(todos["hello there"].completed);`